# How to stop all tests from inside a test or setUp using unittest?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, functional-testing, python-unittest

I'm extending the python 2.7 `unittest` framework to do some function testing. One of the things I would like to do is to stop all the tests from running inside of a test, and inside of a `setUpClass()` method.  Sometimes if a test fails, the program is so broken it is no longer of any use to keep testing, so I want to stop the tests from running.

I noticed that a TestResult has a `shouldStop` attribute, and a `stop()` method, but I'm not sure how to get access to that inside of a test.

Does anyone have any ideas? Is there a better way?

Comment: I use this to abort the test run before running any tests if the application under test is configured with prod settings. (actually, with any non-test settings.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another answer I came up with after a while:

First, I added a new exception:

```
class StopTests(Exception):
"""
Raise this exception in a test to stop the test run.

"""
    pass
```

then I added a new `assert` to my child test class:

```
def assertStopTestsIfFalse(self, statement, reason=''):
    try:
        assert statement            
    except AssertionError:
        result.addFailure(self, sys.exc_info())
```

and last I overrode the `run` function to include this right below the `testMethod()` call:

```
except StopTests:
    result.addFailure(self, sys.exc_info())
    result.stop()
```

I like this better since any test now has the ability to stop all the tests, and there is no cpython-specific code.

Comment: Where is the StopTests raised?

Answer (score 30):

In case you are interested, here is a simple example how you could make a decision yourself about exiting a test suite cleanly with [py.test](http://pytest.org):

```
# content of test_module.py
import pytest
counter = 0
def setup_function(func):
    global counter
    counter += 1
    if counter >=3:
        pytest.exit("decided to stop the test run")

def test_one():
    pass
def test_two():
    pass
def test_three():
    pass
```

and if you run this you get:

```
$ pytest test_module.py 
============== test session starts =================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.6.5 -- pytest-1.4.0a1
test path 1: test_module.py

test_module.py ..

!!!! Exit: decided to stop the test run !!!!!!!!!!!!
============= 2 passed in 0.08 seconds =============
```

You can also put the `py.test.exit()` call inside a test or into a project-specific plugin.

Sidenote: `py.test` natively supports `py.test --maxfail=NUM` to implement stopping after NUM failures.

Sidenote2: `py.test` has only limited support for running tests in the traditional `unittest.TestCase` style.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that testing framework. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Current version of Py.Test: import pytest and then you can do pytest.exit("your message")

Comment: This also works well within a pytest fixture declared in a conftest.py file, with  scope='session', autouse=True. This will run before every test in the project. Calling pytest.exit from here can abort the entire test run before any tests run. I use this to abort tests if they are running using prod config (actually any non-test config)

Answer (score 4):

Currently, you can only stop the tests at the suite level. Once you are in a `TestCase`, the `stop()` method for the `TestResult` is not used when iterating through the tests.

Somewhat related to your question, if you are using python 2.7, you can use the `-f/--failfast` flag when calling your test with `python -m unittest`. This will stop the test at the first failure.

See [25.3.2.1. failfast, catch and buffer command line options](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#failfast-catch-and-buffer-command-line-options)

You can also consider using [Nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.2/) to run your tests and use the `-x, --stop` [flag](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.2/usage.html#cmdoption-x) to stop the test early.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw the failfast option, but I don't always want to fail on the first error, just in selected places. I guess I should edit my question to mention that I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

Though you won't get the usual test reports of the tests run so far, a very easy way to stop the test run from within a `TestCase` method is simply to raise `KeyboardInterrupt` inside the method.

You can see how only `KeyboardInterrupt` is allowed to bubble up inside `unittest`'s test runner by looking at CPython's code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/60a6632a3d2b2dde1c01850f0aa36a22c8dec8dd/Lib/unittest/case.py#L60) inside `testPartExecutor()`.

Comment: I was able to abort all other tests by raising a custom subclass of KeyboardInterrupt in my `setUp()` method, then handling it with result.stop() in my `run()` method. Guilty of insider trading, but helps whittle hundreds of error messages down to one when the database is down.

Answer (score 3):

The OP was about python 2.7. Skip ahead a decade, and for [python 3.1 and above, the way to skip tests in python unittest has had an upgrade](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures), but the documentation could use some clarification (IMHO):

The documentation covers the following:

- Skip All tests after first failure: use `failfast` (only useful if you really don't want to continue any further tests at all, including in other unrelated TestCase classes)
- Skip All tests in a TestCase class: decorate class with `@unittest.skip()`, etc.
- Skip a single method within a TestCase: decorate method with `@unittest.skip()`, etc.
- Conditionally skip a method or a class: decorate with `@unittest.skipIf()` or `@unittest.skipUnless()` etc.
- Conditionally skip a method, but not until something within that method runs: use `self.skipTest()` inside the method (this will skip that method, and ONLY that method, not subsequent methods)

The documentation does not cover the following (as of this writing):

1. Skip all tests within a TestCase class if a condition is met inside the setUpClass method: [solution from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452981/skip-unittest-if-some-condition-in-setupclass-fails) `raise unittest.SkipTest("skip all tests in this class")` (there may be another way, but I'm unaware)
2. Skip all subsequent test methods in a TestCase class after a condition is met in one of the first tests, but still continue to test other unrelated TestCase classes. For this, I propose the following solution...

This solution assumes that you encounter the "bad state" in the middle of a test method, and which could only be noticed in a test method ONLY (i.e., it is not something that could have been determined in the setUpClass method, for whatever reason). Indeed the setUpClass method is the best location for determining whether to proceed if the initial conditions aren't right, but sometimes (as I've encountered) you just don't know until you run some test method. This solution assumes that test methods are in alphabetical order and that subsequent tests methods that you don't want to run after encountering the "bad" state follow alphabetically.

```
import unittest

class SkipMethodsConditionally(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        #this class variable maintains whether or not test methods should continue
        cls.should_continue = True
        #this class variable represents the state of your system. Replace with function of your own
        cls.some_bad_condition = False

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        """setUp runs before every single test method in this class"""
        if not self.__class__.should_continue:
            self.skipTest("no reason to go on.")

    def test_1_fail(self):
        #Do some work here. Let's assume you encounter a "bad state,"" that could 
        #only be noticed in this first test method only, (i.e., it's not something that
        #can be placed in the setUpClass method, for whatever reason)
        self.__class__.some_bad_condition = True

        if self.__class__.some_bad_condition:
            self.__class__.should_continue = False

        self.assertTrue(False,"this test should fail, rendering the rest of the tests irrelevant")

    def test_2_pass(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.__class__.some_bad_condition,"this test would pass normally if run, but should be skipped, because it would fail")
```

The above test will yield the following output:

```
test_1_fail (__main__.SkipMethodsConditionally) ... FAIL
test_2_pass (__main__.SkipMethodsConditionally) ... skipped 'no reason to go on.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1, skipped=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the test loop of `unittest.TestSuite`, there is a `break` condition at the start:

```
class TestSuite(BaseTestSuite):

    def run(self, result, debug=False):
        topLevel = False
        if getattr(result, '_testRunEntered', False) is False:
            result._testRunEntered = topLevel = True

        for test in self:
            if result.shouldStop:
                break
```

So I am using a custom test suite like this:

```
class CustomTestSuite(unittest.TestSuite):
    """ This variant registers the test result object with all ScriptedTests,
        so that a failed Loign test can abort the test suite by setting result.shouldStop
        to True
    """
    def run(self, result, debug=False):
        for test in self._tests:
            test.result = result

        return super(CustomTestSuite, self).run(result, debug)
```

with a custom test result class like this:

```
class CustomTestResult(TextTestResult):
    def __init__(self, stream, descriptions, verbosity):
        super(CustomTestResult, self).__init__(stream, descriptions, verbosity)
        self.verbosity = verbosity
        self.shouldStop = False
```

and my test classes are like:

```
class ScriptedTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, environment, test_cfg, module, test):
        super(ScriptedTest, self).__init__()
        self.result = None
```

Under certain conditions, I then abort the test suite; for example, the test suite starts with a login, and if that fails, I do not have to try the rest:

```
    try:
        test_case.execute_script(test_command_list)
    except AssertionError as e:
        if test_case.module == 'session' and test_case.test == 'Login':
            test_case.result.shouldStop = True
            raise TestFatal('Login failed, aborting test.')
        else:
            raise sys.exc_info()
```

Then I use the test suite in the following way:

```
    suite = CustomTestSuite()

    self.add_tests(suite)

    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=self.environment.verbosity, stream=UnitTestLoggerStream(self.logger),
                                     resultclass=CustomTestResult).run(suite)
```

I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it, but it behaves correctly for my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the `TestCase` class and decided to subclass it.  The class just overrides `run()`.  I copied the method and starting at line 318 in the original class added this:

```
# this is CPython specific. Jython and IronPython may do this differently
if testMethod.func_code.co_argcount == 2:
    testMethod(result)
else:
    testMethod()
```

It has some CPython specific code in there to tell if the test method can accept another parameter, but since I'm using CPython everywhere, this isn't an issue for me.

Answer (score -3):

Use:

```
if condition: 
   return 'pass'
```

Comment: A really bad answer, no explanation and honestly I don't see how it does what OP asked.