# Stop testsuite if a testcase find an error

Tags: python, unit-testing, testcase, test-suite

I have a `testSuite` in Python with several `testCases`.

If a `testCase` fails, `testSuite` continues with the next `testCase`. I would like to be able to stop `testSuite` when a `testCase` fails or be able to decide if the `testSuite` should continue or stop.

Comment: What unit test framework are you using?

Comment: As your unit tests should be independent, this requirement seems odd. Why not execute all unit tests, so you see all failing tests at once?

Answer (score 16):

Since Python 2.7, `unittest` support `failfast` option. It can be either specified by commandline:

```
python -m unittest -f test_module
```

Or when using a script:

```
>>> from unittest import main
>>> main(module='test_module', failfast=True)
```

Unfortunately I haven't yet found out how to specify this option when you are using `setuptools` and `setup.py`.

Comment: Note: this doesn't work if you want to use `unittest discover` (or I just put the flag in the wrong place?).

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers seem to touch on this part of your question:

> ... be able to decide if the testSuite should continue or stop.

You can override the `run()` method within your `TestCase` class and call the `TestResult.stop()` method to signal to the `TestSuite` to stop running tests.

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def run(self, result=None):
        if stop_test_condition():
            result.stop()
            return
        super().run(result=result)
```

Comment: Good answer to the actual question. I was able to bracket my call to super().run() with a handler for a custom exception raised by setUp(). (For [hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45518359/673991) reasons, the exception has to be a subclass of KeyboardInterrupt.)

Answer (score 2):

Use `failfast=True` it will stop running all tests if 1 fails in your test class

Example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(failfast=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Run your tests with nose and use the -x flag. That combined with the --failed flag should give you all you need. So in the top level of your project run

```
nosetests -x # with -v for verbose and -s to no capture stdout
```

Alternatively you could run with

```
nosetests --failed
```

Which will re-run only your failing tests from the test suite

Other useful flags:

```
nosetests --pdb-failure --pdb
```

drops you into a debugger at the point your test failed or errorred

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=<your package name> --cover-html
```

gives you a colorized html page showing which lines on your code have been touched by the test run

A combination of all of those usually gives me what I want.

Comment: Could I do the same without using nose?

Comment: I'm not sure - I know unittest2 brings a lot of new goodies, but I haven't really used them

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually doing unit tests? Or system tests of something else? If the latter, you may be interested in my [Python based testing framework](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/). One of its features is exactly this. You can define test case dependencies and the suite will skip tests with failed dependencies. It also has built-in support to selenium and webdriver. However, it's not so easy to set up. Currently in development but mostly works. Runs on Linux.

Comment: Thanks Keith but I don't know how to use your Python based testing framework to solve my problem.

Answer (score -3):

You can use sys.exit() to close the python interpreter at any point within your testcase.

Comment: I want to close the python interpreter within my testSUITE when running the testSUITE an error happens

Comment: I don't think this is true, `unittest` appeared to catch the `sys.exit` and continue when I tried this solution

Comment: -1: neither `sys.exit()` nor `sys._exit()` actually halt my tests.