# How to exit the script in a unittest test case

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Here is a sample script that checks for a precondition in the very first test case and my intention is to abort the script if the precondition is not met.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import unittest
import sys

class TestMyScript(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_000_prerequisite(self):
        a = 0
        if not a:
            sys.exit()
        return

    def test_001_test1(self):
        print "Inside test 1"
        return

    def test_002_test2(self):
        print "Inside test 2"
        return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

However, the sys.exit() only exits from the individual test case of the suite. It doesn't exit the whole script.

I understand that unittest treats each test case individually which is why any exceptions caused by any testcase are handled by the test runner and it proceeds to the next test case.

But I want the script to kill itself. How do I do that?

Here is the output of my script:

```
./temp.py
EInside test 1
.Inside test 2
.
======================================================================
ERROR: test_000_prerequisite (__main__.TestMyScript)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./temp.py", line 9, in test_000_prerequisite
    sys.exit()
SystemExit

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

My guess is that I have to mess around with TestRunner and kill the script if a test case returns some signal. But I am not sure how to really achieve it.

Comment: You're catching `SystemExit`.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901338/python-unittest-cancel-all-tests-if-a-specific-test-fails

Comment: Duplicate, see link above.

Comment: Thank you guys for the response. The above thread lead to another which solved my problem. The easiest way is to add failfast flag. I updated my post with the solution.

Comment: If you have found a solution for your question, I would recommend submitting it as an answer, then accepting the answer.  That way others will not continue coming to your question hoping to help when you have already solved the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop testsuite if a testcase find an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813837/stop-testsuite-if-a-testcase-find-an-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the answer:

[Stop testsuite if a testcase find an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813837/stop-testsuite-if-a-testcase-find-an-error)

Here is the change I need to make when calling `unittest.main()`. The `failfast` keyword argument stops the script after the first failure.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(failfast=True)
```

p.s. `failfast` keyword argument is only available for python 2.7+

p.p.s. you can also use `failfast` on `unittest.TextTestRunner()`

Comment: It would be great to have an example with TextTestRunner (if you're not using unittest.main)