# Skip unittest if some-condition in SetUpClass fails

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I was playing with `pyUnit` framework for unittest testing of my application. Is there any any way to skip all the tests in class if certain condition in setUpClass fails?

Currently, I am setting up environment (creating resources, configuring global settings) in setUpClass. But, if any of these resource creation fails..I am raising exception. Instead of that I want to skip the whole test suite.

Answer (score 42):

Got the answer:

For those who gets stuck here-

unittest can be skipped from setUpClass in following way-

```
raise unittest.SkipTest(message)
```

Comment: Here is the doc http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures

Comment: you can also raise this from the tests themselves if they determine they shouldn't be run for whatever reason.

Comment: Is there a way we can skip it without raising exception? I want to see 0 exception and 0 failures when we skip it in setupclass. This method shows exception in the run results.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of explicitly raising the SkipTest exception, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures) suggests using TestCase.skipTest(). For example:

```
def setUp(self):
    if skip_tests_flag:
        self.skipTest('skipped test due to skip_tests_flag')
```

Comment: yes, but you spend additional time in setUpClass and setUp methods for the test which you are going to skip

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko But if the condition can only be evaluated in the `setUp` class, it's only possible there. Also, if you use inheritance, that's the way to go. And this is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @sebix thanks, OP asked clearly that skip shall be done if condition in setUpClass fails. Not sure that there mentioning on inheritance in that use case.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Sorry for the incomprehensible wording. My last sentence did not refer to the one before.