# Skipping Python test when dependency not available

Tags: python, selenium, testing, python-unittest

I'm poking at a Python 2.7 project while not really being familiar with Python. There is a test that fails when Firefox is not installed since it uses selenium which uses Firefox. I'd like the test to skip itself when it cannot be run.

Test class

```
class SeleniumAuthTestCase(SeleniumTestCase):
```

The error I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/vagrant/source/some/path/tests/selenium/test_auth.py", line 14, in setUpClass
    super(cls, cls).setUpClass()
  File "/mnt/vagrant/source/some/path/testcases.py", line 14, in setUpClass
    cls.driver = Firefox()
  File "/some/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.binary = firefox_binary or capabilities.get("binary", FirefoxBinary())
  File "/some/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 47, in __init__
    self._start_cmd = self._get_firefox_start_cmd()
  File "/some/path/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 163, in _get_firefox_start_cmd
    " Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox")
RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox
```

I figured out that there is a way to have [individual test methods skipped via annotation](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures). However the error here occurs before any of the test methods are invoked: in `setUpClass` in the parent class.

I also figured out I can overload the method:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    super(SeleniumAuthTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
```

So I could check there if the dependency is loaded, and if it is not, avoid calling the parent class. On top of that I could set some flag to indicate if the thing is loaded, and then have a annotation for each method that checks it. This is very clumsy though, and I'd much more like to do something like this PHPUnit code:

```
public function setUp() {
    if ( true ) {
        $this->markTestSkipped();
    }
}
```

How is this normally done in Python?

Comment: Likely you'll need to add some `except ImportError:`, then use `@unittest.skipIf` or `unittest.TestCase.skipTest`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452981/skip-unittest-if-some-condition-in-setupclass-fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [approach that sbarzowski linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452981/skip-unittest-if-some-condition-in-setupclass-fails) worked for me.

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    try:
        Firefox()
    except:
        raise unittest.SkipTest("Selenium webdriver needs Firefox, which is not available")

    super(SeleniumAuthTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
```