# Exitting Python Webdriver Script with no error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need help to exit a test without getting error. I have this code:

```
tabla = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".tablaSolicitudes")
for estado in tabla.find_elements_by_tag_name("td"):
    e = estado.text
if e.find("Multiadhesion") != -1:
    print("La solicitud " + solicitudes[i] + " se encuentra con MultiAdhesion. Finaliza el Test.")
    sys.exit()
```

If that condition is true, the test should end. The point is that, having it like that, i get this error:

```
sys.exit()
SystemExit

----------------------
Ran 1 test in 139.733s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

But the test is OK, so, how can I make a proper "test exit" so that i don´t get this error?.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

`sys.exit()` raises a `SystemExit` exception, which you can test with:

```
with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
    your_method()
```

Now your test should succeed.

Comment: Works, but goes on with the execution, does not end up the test.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stop the tests, then one of the ways is using force stop `-f` available in `unittest`

> -f, --fail: fast Stop the test run on the first error or failure.

try running the module using -f option:

```
python sample.py -f
```

But, it won't mark the test as PASS and you should remove `sys.exit()` from `try..except...` block

If you have control on tests to run, then you can do as follows:

1. set `shouldStop = True` in the method you want to exit (refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.shouldStop).
2. check after test method runs (each test method returns TestResult object to its caller), whether it is `True` or `False`, if it is True, call `STOP()` method. (refer [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.stop))

**OR**

Another option is `pytest` framework which provides the facility to exit the run. Add the following line wherever you want to exit:

```
pytest.exit("decided to stop the test run")
```

Reference:

1. [How to stop all tests from inside a test or setUp using unittest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806695/how-to-stop-all-tests-from-inside-a-test-or-setup-using-unittest)

---

**Old Answer:**

replace `sys.exit()` as follows:

```
try:
    sys.exit()
except:
    print "its ok"
```

> sys.exit() returns SystemExit exception.

I assume you are using `unittest` framework. A test is markd as `PASS` only when there is no Failure/Exception in the test method. as sys.exit() throwing exception, `unittest` marks it as `FAIL`.

What we do is, handle the exception in the test method itself, so no exception/failure is thrown, which makes `unittest` to mark that test method as `PASS`.

Comment: Doing this, the test tries to go on with the execution (after that code, the method keeps) :/ Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: Awesome! Despite solving it otherway, it's close to be what i was looking for. In tools like UFT, you have that sentence ExitTest and that's it, but webdriver makes it a bit more complex. Thank you all very much for your answers, you really know what you are talking about!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `sys` defined higher up in your code but that could be why the test is having issues.

To close a Selenium browser test (which I believe you are using, inferring from the `selenium-webdriver` tag), normally a `.close()` or `.quit()` tag is used. Assuming `sys` is the browser, at the end of the your `if` statement, you would use `sys.close` or `sys.quit` to close the browser.

> `.close()` will close a tab within a testing browser. `.quit()` will close the browser window.

If you need more help, check out [Selenium Python Bindings Documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html). It's always been a big help for me when writing python/selenium tests.

Comment: sys only show me the option "exit", not close() or quit(), If I do self.driver.quit() it fails too.